# Need one VM to run project management and multiple revision systems SVN, CVS, and PVCS

Tags: project-management, subversion

I'm looking to find a mostly turnkey solution but am open to ideas both paid and free.

I Need to build a VM that would provide the following functions:

> project management
>
> multiple revision systems SVN, CVS, and PVCS

I've been looking into Turnkey Linux VM's and am unsure of what child distro to select or to just roll my own.

I know PVCS is a bit "Legacy" so I'm open to converting to another system but since the users are used to Serena PVCS I would need to have something that feels as similar as possible to the old system to help reduce or eliminate the learning curve. I also need the same thing for CVS. Since I have installed CVS from scratch on a bare RHEL VM I'm sure it would be easy enough to install and configure on Turnkey but I'm hoping someone has come across an environment like this before that can offer some insight on the issue. The next piece is that we need something for managing projects centrally so everyone can finally get away from spreadsheets. Below are the two Turnkey Linux child distro's that I've been looking at but I'm confused why TRAC is smaller but yet has the same REPO's already built in with webmin.

The [Revision Control VM](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/revision-control) is slightly larger at 211MB for the base ISO VS [TRAC](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/trac) which is 181MB for the base ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Turnkey Trac](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/trac) distribution and telling the PVCS users to learn to use SVN - as a centralized VCS it comes as less of a shock than DVCSs such as git/hg/etc.  *I have just finished porting nearly 50 PVCS repositories to SVN - they contained a total of about 40k files and up to 15 years of history so **it can be done** - the biggest battle was over not putting binaries into a source control system.*

The Turnkey trac system includes:

- trac ticketing system for defect management,
- Git,
- Bazaar,
- Mercurial and
- Subversion

You should be able to add a CSV server reasonably easily but, again, I would strongly suggest getting the users to move over to SVN.

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is basically the same sort of ticket tracking, project planning and wiki system as several well known sites such as sourceforge use/used, the [V1.0 demo](http://trac.edgewall.org/demo-1.0/report/2) tracker page is below:
[image: Traker]

Comment: Will this also suffice for a decent project management solution as well? What about bug tracking?

Comment: Adding to answer above.